# Converting to "int" failed for parameter "name"

Tags: python, request, discord, discord.py

Is there any solve for this?

```
async def cosmetic(ctx, name : int):
    response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br")
    embed=discord.Embed(
    title=f"{name}", color=0x9c3030
)
    embed.add_field(f'Rarity: {BrCosmeticRarity}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Isn't name supposed to be of string type?

Comment: And where are you converting name to ```int``` ?

Comment: so it's (name) right?

Comment: it requires an argument so i converted name to `int`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! To make the question clearer please add what did you execute and what is the output of your run. In addition, provide the desired output and explain the discrepency between the two. That would help answering! good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You're explicitly converting `name` to an `int` via

```py
async def cosmetic(ctx, name : int):
```

---

`name` however isn't supposed to be of type int, because it is probably meant to be a string. To fix your issue, set the right type for `name` in your function declaration

---

```py
async def cosmetic(ctx, name : str):
```

---

```py
async def cosmetic(ctx, name : str):
    response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br")
    embed=discord.Embed(
        title=f"{name}", color=0x9c3030
    )
    embed.add_field(f'Rarity: {BrCosmeticRarity}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```